# Apache won't follow Symlink

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a LAMP server (Ubuntu 12.10) setup on my development machine. It is a T60 modified with an SSD.

The server base is in /var/www. Apache has the following config:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  AllowOverride all
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

I'm currently developing a [SilverStripe](http://www.silverstripe.org/) CMS featured site. The folder for the server is /var/www/sfk/. The framework and all cms relavant features are in their respective folders. The only folder that need to be modified would be the /var/www/sfk/mysite folder. Because of that I want to keep the mysite folder under my home directory and symlink it into the server folder. So here is what I've done:

```
ln -s ~/sfk/mysite/ /var/www/sfk/
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/sfk/mysite -R
```

ls tells me the following:

```
/var/www/sfk (exerpt)

drwxr-xr-x  3 marvin www-data 4096 Nov 16 16:53 assets
drwxr-xr-x 12 marvin www-data 4096 Nov 16 16:53 cms
drwxr-xr-x 29 marvin www-data 4096 Nov 16 16:53 framework
-rw-r--r--  1 marvin www-data 2410 Nov 16 16:53 index.php
lrwxrwxrwx  1 marvin www-data   24 Nov 20 17:45 mysite -> /home/marvin/sfk/mysite/
-rw-rw-r--  1 marvin www-data  514 Nov 16 16:55 _ss_environment.php
drwxr-xr-x  4 marvin www-data 4096 Nov 16 16:53 themes
```

and

```
ls /var/www/sfk/mysite/

drwxrwxr-x 6 marvin www-data 4096 Nov 16 00:15 code
drwxrwxr-x 2 marvin www-data 4096 Nov 16 11:51 _config
-rwxrwxr-x 1 marvin www-data 2685 Nov 16 15:39 _config.php
drwxrwxr-x 2 marvin www-data 4096 Nov 16 00:15 css
drwxrwxr-x 2 marvin www-data 4096 Nov 16 00:15 images
drwxrwxr-x 2 marvin www-data 4096 Nov 16 00:15 javascript
drwxrwxr-x 5 marvin www-data 4096 Nov 16 00:15 templates
```

This is literally the same setup I have on my desktop machine. The problem I have is that the mysite/ folder is just not recognized. I'm thankful for every advice I get. I'm frustrated because I'm stuck with this issue for hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure the `www-data` account has the ability to traverse every single directory component of `/home/marvin/sfk/mysite/`?  So `www-data` has to have access to `home`, `marvin`, `sfk`, and `mysite`.  You probably need to have `o+x` on every component of that path.  When a symlink is followed, the user following the symlink must have the ability to actually get to the destination folder/file.

If you don't want to grant `www-data` access to your folder, then you might want to look at a bind mount instead.

Comment: or just add www-data to the group marvin (`gpasswd -a www-data marvin`)

Comment: @rbtux, I suppose you could, but then your web server can probably read anything stored in his home directory.  I am not sure he wants that.  Best to stick with minimal permissions if you can.

Comment: as he said development server, I don't think it would be an issue. But of course this would grant more permissions than needed.

Comment: Okay, I had no rights given to the folder /home/marvin. Thank you for your answer. Worked.
@rbtux: I prefer minimal permissions, even though it is a developer machine.

Answer (score 1):

What are the permissions on your home directory and the sub directories, as they need to be accessible to the Apache user e.g.

```
chmod 755 ~/ ~/sfk ~mysite
```

Comment: After a week of struggling, this was my issue. Thank you, your suggestion fixed it.